# How to display a converted string from a list without null value?

Tags: java

I have the following piece of code

```
String Roletext=null;
for(String text1:Rolelist1)
{
    Roletext+=text1+",";
}
```

I want to convert a list into a string. And then I display the value. It takes the null as it first value. If it is not initialized, then it will show error. Please help.

Comment: Don't use `+=`. Use [`StringBuidler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead. Please. And follow [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html). Please.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution for you question:**

```
String Roletext="";
for(String text1:Rolelist1)
{
    Roletext +=text1+",";
}
```

Reason for this is when you do concatenation with `null` , the string appends the value with `"null"`

**My suggestion:**

I suggest you to use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of String concatenation.

```
   StringBuilder b=new StringBuilder();
    for(String text1:Rolelist1)
    {
          b.append(text1).append(",");
    }

String Roletext=b.toString().replaceAll(",$", "");//get rid of last comma
```

Comment: It is better to use StringBuilder.deleteCharAt(), otherwise you defeat the purpose of using stringbuilder

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize your String first

```
String Roletext="";
int i;
for(i = 0;i < Rolelist1.size() - 1;i++)
{
    Roletext+=Rolelist1.get(i)+",";
}
Roletext+=Rolelist1.get(i);
```

Or for better performance you can use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
sb.append("Your String");
```

Comment: Better using regular `for` loop and prevent adding `,` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Define it like this:

```
String Roletext ="";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect example where using a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) is recommended:

```
StringBuilder roleText = new StringBuilder();
for(String text1:Rolelist1) {
    if(roleText.length() > 0) {
        roleText.append(",");
    }
    roleText.append(text1);
}
```

By the way: The if construct on length is the one I always use to prevent any leading or trailing commas, it's the most elegant solution to prevent this imo ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to inititalize the string first.

```
String Roletext="";
```

But it is not good practice to use a `String` object for building a  string using a loop. Use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String text1 : rolelist1) {
    sb.append(text1);
}
roletext = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String Roletext="";
for(String text1:Rolelist1)
{
    Roletext+=text1+",";
}
```

now it will not take any null values,initially the string is empty if String text="".
But if we are initializing it with null then String takes first value as null.
Null means some random value it doesn't means empty.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
String Roletext=null;
Rolelist1.remove(Collections.singleton(null)); //This line will remove all null from Rolelist1
for(String text1:Rolelist1) 
{
    Roletext+=text1+",";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String Roletext = Arrays.toString(Rolelist1.toArray());
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Edited